# Android Emulator Size Settings

Tags: android, size, settings, emulation

I'm trying to test my app on a number of different sized screens to make sure it displays correctly. I'm finding it hard to setup the emulator to show the different sized screens. Can someone please help in providing the settings needed to show an emulator for x-large, large, medium and small sized screens please?

Any help in working with the emulators would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: If your code allows it, you can also do an initial visual cross-check of a bunch of different screen sizes all at the same time through the new Android Studio. http://www.prembharath.com/wp-content/gallery/android-studio/multiple-preview.png (of course, this preview mode won't work if you're doing opengl, or if you're drawing things yourself on a canvas). And yes, I realize this isn't the question you were asking. Checking with the emulator is not the same as checking with the preview simulator. I just thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: Hi @Stephan Branczyk, thank you very much for your comment. This looks great, I wasn't aware of the Android Studio and I've just looked and it allows you to import your Eclipse project in, so I'll definately give that a look, thank you. How is it to develop in, is it similar to that of Eclipse?

Comment: You may need to export your project as a gradle project first. And yes, Android Studio is similar to Eclipse, but it's still a learning curve. In my opinion, it's already much-much better than Eclipse, but it is still quite unstable (even the stable branch). The current stable version is fine now, but don't be so quick to update it the next time it gets updated. Updates occasionally introduce major regressive bugs. Eventually, it will get better, but as it stands, Google did say it's just a Preview version (it's not even called a Beta yet).

Comment: By the way, you may even want to try http://www.genymotion.com/ (even the free version should work for you). The only difference right now is that their AVDs are already created and that they have a very easy UI to use. That being said, even if you do end up using them, you should still learn how to create your own AVDs yourself (and you should learn how to create Intel x86 AVDs as well, since speed can be a pretty big issue too, although the genymotion solution should work just as fast as the Intel HAXM emulator).

Answer (score 1):

When you run your AVD, there are two tabs:

1 - Android Virtual devices with devices you created.

and

2 -  *Device Definitions* -> **click on this one.**

Now you can pick different devices with different screen sizes, densities, resolutions...basically all the important combinations you would want to test it with(and more)

**Select one** and click on the **right side menu button -> create AVD**.

Comment: Hi @JanBo, thank you very much for your comment. I'll do that and check back in with you, appreciate the help